# form_alter hook in a ctools content-type plugin not called

Tags: nodes, forms, chaos-tool-suite

I'm writing a ctools content-type plugin to use it as a panels pane. In my plugin code I try to use the form_alter hook at render for the login_form (not for the edit forms). But the hook seems not to be called. It makes no difference if I use the generic form_alter hook or the particular with the form-id in the function name. Both work neither.

```
/**
 * Modify the User Login form
 */
function justloginpane_content_type_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);


  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('A form with a fieldset'),
  );

    // Enable AJAX
    $form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array(
                                  'callback' => 'ajax_example_submit_driven_callback',
                                  'wrapper' => 'box', 
                              );
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'TESTSUBMITTEXT';

}
```

I thought it worked once, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Where is the code? It needs to either be in the .module file, or another file which is explicitly required/included into the .module file. Otherwise Drupal won't find it

Comment: Like @Clive said, you're probably writing the alter function in the `.inc` file of your plugin folder. Move it to the module file, or include the plugin file from the module file.

Comment: Yes it's in the .inc file. I'll try moving it to the .module file.

Comment: @Clive and @AjitS: it's also not called if I put the function in the .module file. My module's name is `justloginpane` and the alter function's name is  `justloginpane_form_user_login_alter`